# Add an if statement to change css of certain item

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

I have created a website and within the website there is a to do list, so the user can insert certain to do items, the info that the user inputs is saved into a database, inside the table i have 'id', 'content'(which is the to-do item) and 'status' I have put status in here as I want the user to be able to click done, partially done or not done, so the values are 1,2 and 3.

```
// update the list view
for (var i=0; i< res.length; i++){
    $("<li/>", {"id": res[i].id, "text": res[i].content + res[i].status}).appendTo(todo.list);
    // Extend the width if msg is too long
    if(res[i].content.length >= 35){
        $('#'+res[i].id).css("height","50px");
```

The to-do list is in JavaScript, I would like an if statement so that the if the status is 1 it will turn green, and similar for the other two, just with different colours, but i am having trouble getting this code correct. Thanks.

Comment: Why would it turn green with a different height? Also, elements must have position to have dimensions.

Comment: no this is just code within the todo.js I havent figured out code to change the color yet

Comment: So I have it so that the status is printed beside the todo item, but I want it to instead chahge the color depending on the status value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you would need to do is add a class to the li item, then in your css target this class with the different colour:

```
$("<li/>", {"id": res[i].id, "text": res[i].content + res[i].status, "class": 'status-' + res[i].status}).appendTo(todo.list);
```

Then in your css:

```
.status-1 { color: red };
.status-2 { color: green };
```

etc (depends if it's color of the text or background)

Thanks

Comment: One more question, this has worked for one of the items,but will not change more than 1 item, any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, that should have be fine, have you checked that the correct status number is coming through within the for statement?
Try doing some console.logs and see what is coming through and what happens with just:
console.log('status-' + res[i].status) as well.

Comment: Thanks i got it working, I can now change the clour by changing the status in the database to different numbers, how would i go about enabling the user to change this is the front end, with buttons, with the value of done, partially done and not done, so that it would then change in the backend and then change color for the user?

Comment: I'm not sure about updating the database even more so without seeing more code, but you can link the button to add/remove the class when they update the status